# JQuery Mobile page event not firing

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile

I'm using Wordpress and JQuery Mobile ver 1.4.5. My problem is the following code is not working only the `$( document ).ready` is working fine. I'm new in wordpress and i don't know what is wrong.

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGECREATE');
});
$(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGEINIT');
});
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGEBEFORESHOW');
});
$(document).on('pageshow','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('PAGESHOW');
});
$(document).on('mobileinit','[data-role=page]', function(){
  console.log('mobileinit');
});

$( document ).ready(function(){
    console.log("ready");
});
```

This is how I insert JQM in funtion.php

```
wp_deregister_script('jquerypremobile'); 
wp_register_script( 'jquerypremobile', get_template_directory_uri() .'/jmobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerypremobile' );
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I think call the every function in sequence .because jquery compile in sequence so better to check the sequence of event then call .Hope it will help.